# Java implementation of singular value decomposition for large sparse matrices

Tags: java, text-mining, large-data-volumes, large-data

I'm just wondering if anyone out there knows of a java implementation of singular value decomposition (SVD) for large sparse matrices? I need this implementation for latent semantic analysis (LSA).

I tried the packages from UJMP and JAMA but they choke when the number of row >= 1000 and col >= 500. If anyone can point me to psuedocode or something out there, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750463/singular-value-decomposition-implementation) which was nearly the same was to try [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/).

Comment: well, the code for the class SingularValueDecomposition in both Colt and JAMA are nearly identical. moreover, the code only works for when m > n (number of rows is greater than number of columns). also, i think the algorithms are not optimized for sparse matrices.

Comment: the m > n condition doesn't really bother me. in fact, for me, 99.99% of the time, m > n, will always be the case (rows represent words and cols represent documents). it's just that this constraint isn't clearly documented.

Comment: where m = 2810, n = 2809, it took 25 minutes using colt. not bad.

Comment: look at la4j.decomposition. It might help.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [list of Java numerical libraries at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#Java). The NIST library, which is quite good, unfortunately does not deal with sparse matrices. I'm not too familiar with the other packages. You might take a look at [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/index.html); it's also quite high quality and does handle sparse matrices for some operations; I don't know about SVD, although I imagine it does. I've also heard that [UJMP](http://www.ujmp.org/) is also worth a look.

EDIT: Sorry to hear that UJMP doesn't handle your problem. I had heard that it was worth a look.

Comment: thanks. that list helped. if anyone is interested, the apache commons math package does have a SVD implementation. it iterates only 30 times, and throws an exception. digging a little deeper into the code, it is not apparent how to increase this (as there are classes within classes within classes).

Comment: It is using Jama svd in back.